# Does passing a File into a thread which required a Context, risk a memory leak?

Tags: android, android-context, internal-storage

If I use a Context to generate a file pointing to the internal storage location

```
final File saveFile = context.getFilesDir();
```

Will I leak the context if I submit saveFile to a thread, and the phone gets rotated?

I know if I passed the Context in it would leak it on rotate, but I'm not 100% sure what happens if I pass an item in that was dependent on the context in the first place.

I think it's safe, but thought it best to check.

Comment: you are fine. it only uses the context to determine the file directory on that one line. after all that "File" is really just a string of the location of the dir.

Comment: I thought that's all it was, but I wasn't confident enough.  Thanks!!